# What is getTcpBytesSent(mWhich);

Tags: android

What does the function getTcpBytesSent(mWhich) do? It is a BatteryStats package function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets the number of Tcp Bytes Sent.

TCP is the network protocol used for most IP traffic (UDP can also be used).

This stat is relevant to battery usage because radio interfaces (Wifi/Bluetooth/GPRS) all draw power, and sending/receiving data reduces battery life.

Comment: so it doesn't collect 3g traffic? if so which function can i use to collect it?